# Check to see if c:\temp exists on local system - PERL / RegEx

Tags: regex, perl

What is wrong with my syntax:

```
if (-d =~ /c:\\[Tt][Ee][Mm][Pp]/i) {
print "There is a directory c:\\TEMP already..\n!";
}
else {
print "didn't find";
}
```

Comment: I keep getting "didn't find"..

Comment: See people's suggestions below, also what do you need to 'i' regex flag when you already take care of all possible cases in the brackets? its useless and a performance hit.

Comment: I figured it out: if (-e "c:\\temp") {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `opendir(my $dh,'C:\temp\\' or die;if(-d $dh){...`.

Check out `perldoc -f '-x'`

Comment: The above code works, but I am trying to figure out how to implement regular expression

Comment: From the above perldoc:  "A file test, where `X` is one of the letters listed below [including `d`]. This unary operator takes one argument, either a filename, a filehandle, or a dirhandle".  So, you need a filename, filehandle, or dirhandle, not a regex.

Comment: I figured it out: if (-e "c:\\temp") {

Answer (score 3):

Instead of checking for C:\Temp or one of its many variants, you should either use a [perl module written for handling temp files](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Temp.html) or use the [Win32 API to obtain the temp folder](http://search.cpan.org/~acalpini/Win32-API-0.41/API.pm).

Comment: I figured it out: if (-e "c:\\temp") {

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: if (-e "c:\temp") {